Applescript for batch pairwise comparison of word files
I have a similar situation. I need to perform a large number of pairwise track change comparisons of word files, and the comparison must be done in Word.
I used applescript to perform this, but I'm really not good at this at all and the resulting script doesn't work. Could anyone have a look?
I start with a CSV list of file pairs (old filepath in left column, new filepath in right column). The script is supposed to use that list, and compare the two files in each row, then save the file as a new TC file using the "new file" name with a "_TC" suffix.
-- Prompt user for CSV file

set csvFile to choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file containing the file paths:"

-- Prompt user for output folder

set outputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder to save the comparison files:"

-- Read the CSV file

set fileContent to read csvFile as text
set fileLines to paragraphs of fileContent

-- Function to split text by delimiter

on splitText(theText, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theTextItems to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theTextItems
end splitText

-- Function to trim whitespace

on trimText(theText)
    set theText to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theText & " | xargs")
    return theText
end trimText

-- Loop through the CSV file and perform comparisons

repeat with i from 1 to count of fileLines
    set fileLine to item i of fileLines
    set {oldFile, newFile} to my splitText(fileLine, ",")

    -- Trim whitespace

    set oldFile to my trimText(oldFile)
    set newFile to my trimText(newFile)

    -- Extract file names for saving

    set fileName to do shell script "basename " & quoted form of newFile
    set comparisonFile to (outputFolder as string) & fileName & "_TC.docx"

    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
    
    
        -- Perform the comparison

        set compareDoc to compare newFile with oldFile
    
        -- Save the comparison result as a .docx file

        save as compareDoc file name comparisonFile file format format document
    
        -- Close the documents

        close oldDoc saving no
        close newDoc saving no
        close compareDoc saving no
    end tell
end repeat


sorry... new to this. It's not really relevant.

I made a few changes but this is only tested for a single pair of documents.
- Prompt user for CSV file

set csvFile to choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file containing the file paths:"

-- Prompt user for output folder.

-- Word wants to work with POSIX paths and names these days.
set outputFolder to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder to save the comparison files:")

-- Read the CSV file

set fileContent to read csvFile as text
set fileLines to paragraphs of fileContent

-- Function to split text by delimiter

on splitText(theText, theDelimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theDelimiter
    set theTextItems to text items of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theTextItems
end splitText

-- Function to trim whitespace

on trimText(theText)
    set theText to (do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theText & " | xargs")
    return theText
end trimText

-- Loop through the CSV file and perform comparisons

repeat with i from 1 to count of fileLines
    set fileLine to item i of fileLines
    
    set {oldFile, newFile} to my splitText(fileLine, ",")
    
    -- Trim whitespace
    
    set oldFile to my trimText(oldFile)
    set newFile to my trimText(newFile)
    
    -- Extract file names for saving
    
    -- need the " .docx" to remove the existing .docx
    -- there's probably a much simpler way to do this.
    set fileName to do shell script "basename " & quoted form of newFile & " .docx"
    -- POSIX again (should have been fixed by the change above to the outputFolder
    -- assignment but I've left it in)
    set comparisonFile to ((outputFolder as string) & fileName & "_TC.docx") as POSIX file
    
    tell application "Microsoft Word"
        activate
        
        -- ensure we start with no open documents
        repeat with doc in documents
            close doc saving no
        end repeat
        
        open newFile -- this will be the activedocument
        
        set newDoc to active document
                
        -- Perform the comparison. this should create a new document which will be the
        -- active document
        
        compare newDoc path oldFile
        
        -- Save the comparison result as a .docx file
        
        save as active document file name comparisonFile file format format document
        
        -- Close the documents
        
        close active document saving no
        close newDoc saving no
        
    end tell
    
end repeat

